# Trouble deleting a folder full of files

Tags: c#

This should be very simple but I'm not sure what's wrong. I'm trying to delete all the files in a folder using `File.Delete`.

This is what I have so far:

```
DirectoryInfo ImageFolder = new DirectoryInfo(Program.FolderPath + @"\Images");
foreach (var File in ImageFolder.GetFiles())
{
    File.Delete(File.FullName);
}
```

Then the ".Delete" becomes underlined and says no overload for method delete takes 1 argument.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you fully qualify: System.IO.File.Delete(...

Comment: Just in case it's not clear from the answers, you have an ambiguity between both `File`: one is your local object and the other is the framework class. You are trying to access the framework class' `Delete` but your object's `FullName`. There's no way the compiler to guess your intentions and by `File` only understands your local object. You should either use the full class name with namespace included (like the comment above) or, much better, rename your local object. BTW, local variable names should start with lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the naming of the variable:

```
DirectoryInfo ImageFolder = new DirectoryInfo(Program.FolderPath + @"\Images");
foreach (var file in ImageFolder.GetFiles())
{
    File.Delete(file.FullName);
}
```

Comment: @Will : Remember to mark the answer that solved your problem as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark on its left.

Comment: Or you could directly call `file.Delete()`.

Answer (score 1):

To delete folder full of file use:

```
Directory.Delete(string directoryName, bool recursive);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx

Or from your code above, use:

```
DirectoryInfo ImageFolder = new DirectoryInfo(Program.FolderPath + @"\Images");
foreach (var fileInfo in ImageFolder.GetFiles())
{
    fileInfo.Delete(); //this is FileInfo.Delete
    // or
    // File.Delete(fileInfo.FullName);
    // dont use reserve "File" as your variable name
}
```

Remember, you are calling FileInfo, not File

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is called Namespace Ambiguity.

In your own code or a reference DLL you probably have a method called Delete in a Class called File that doesn't support a single string parameter.

To fix the problem fully qualify File.Delete with System.IO, eg:

`System.IO.File.Delete`